# Can one know how large a factorial would be before calculating it?

Tags: language-agnostic, gmp, factorial

I'm using GMP to calculate very large factorials (e.g. 234234!). Is there any way of knowing, before one does the calculation, how many digits long the result will (or might) be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **logarithm of the factorial** can be used to calculate the number of digits that the factorial number will take:

[image: logn!]

This can be easily translated to an algorithmic form:

```
//Pseudo-code
function factorialDigits (n) 
  var result = 0;

  for(i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    result += log10(n);

  return result;
```

Comment: This isn't the most efficient method, but by Knuth, every programmer should know enough math to think of it almost immediately.

Comment: except me, of course, who doesn't know enough math (or maths, as we call it in this country.)

Comment: shouldn't that be: `result += log10(i);`?

Answer (score 12):

You can transform [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) formula using simple logarithmic math to get you the number of digits:

```
n!         ~ sqr(2*pi*n) * (n/e)^n
log10(n!)  ~ log10(2*pi*n)/2 + n*log10(n/e)
```

Hardware float math is sufficient for this, which makes it lightning fast.

Comment: it will require to calculate n^n, again a costly calulation

Comment: I just remembered that I actually once faced exactly the same problem and how I solved it

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that Stirling's formula gives an *under*-estimate of n!. For most practical purposes where you need to know the number of digits, an under-estimation is the fast lane to a buffer overrun. So you probably need to do a bit of investigation and jiggering to get an *over*-estimate, but I think the Wikipedia page contains enough information.

Answer (score 3):

Stirling's Approximation gives an approximation of of the size of n!

[image]

See the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) page for the derivation.

Comment: As Rats remarked on my previously identical reply, calculating n^n is not really feasible either. It quickly goes beyond what even a double-precision float can hold, and using Java BigInteger, calculation time on my (admittedly slow) system were 30s for 100,000, 130s for 200,000 - you can see where that's going.

Answer (score 2):

it would be

```
nlog(n) - n + log(n(1 + 4n(1 + 2n)))/6 + log(pi)/2
```

see topic "rate of growth" @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial
Srinivasa Ramanujan method

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

It says n! ~= sqrt(2*Pi*n)*(n/e)^n. To get the number of digits, take 1+log(n!)/log(10).

Comment: to clarify - 1+log(n)/log(10) would give the number of digits of n, not of n!

Comment: it will require to calculate n! any ways :), that is not what boost wants to do

Answer (score 1):

Well about four people have mentioned Stirling so... another option is a LUT storing the number of digits for each of the first N factorials. Assuming 4 bytes for the integer and 4 bytes for the number of digits, you could store the first 1,000,000 factorials in around 8MB.

Comment: You still have to calculate the values for the table though. And I doubt you want to spend a few years or decades doing, which is what you would, calculating it straightforward.

Comment: Well, you'd calculate all N factorials from 1! to N! in a single consecutive pass. So you'd be looking at N total multiplications and at some point you'd bog down in heavy-number arithmetic but should this take decades? What's the correlation between N and processing time?